# While creating index add where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a DB migration script in ruby .

How to add the where clause in the migration script

```
unless index_exists?(:hotel_room_types, [:hotel_id, :dynamic_price_from])
      add_index :hotel_room_types, [:hotel_id, :dynamic_price_from], 
      unique: true, where: (status =1), name: 'by_hotel_id_from'
 end

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
```

LINE 1: ...otel_room_types"  ("hotel_id", "dynamic_price_from") WHERE 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the `where` as a string

```
add_index :hotel_room_types, [:hotel_id, :dynamic_price_from], 
  unique: true, where: 'status = 1', name: 'by_hotel_id_from'
```